# Java Dynamic Binding

Tags: java, array, polymorphism, binding, dynamic

I am having trouble understanding the OOP Polymorphic principl of Dynamic Binding ( Late Binding ) in Java. I looked for question pertaining to java, and wasn't sure if a overall answer to how dynamic binding works would pertain to Java Dynamic Binding, I wrote this question.

Given:

```
class Person
{
     private String name;

     Person(intitialName)
     {
          name = initialName;
     }

     // irrelevant methods is here.

     // Overides Objects method
     public void writeOutput()
     {
          println(name);
     }
}

class Student extends Person
{

     private int studentNumber;

     Student(String intitialName, int initialStudentNumber)
     {
     super(intitialName);
     studentNumber = initialStudentNumber;
     }

     // irrellevant methods here...

     // overides Person, Student and Objects method
     public void writeOutput()
     {
      super.writeOutput();
      println(studentNumber);
     }   
  }

class Undergaraduate extends Student
{

     private int level;

     Undergraduate(String intitialName, int initialStudentNumber,int initialLevel)
     {
     super(intitialName,initialStudentNumber);
     level = initialLevel;
     }

     // irrelevant methods is here.

     // overides Person, Student and Objects method
     public void writeOutput()
     {
      super.writeOutput();
      println(level);
     }

  }
```

I am wondering. if I had an array called person declared to contain objects of type Person:

```
  Person[] people = new Person[2];
  person[0] = new Undergraduate("Cotty, Manny",4910,1);
  person[1] = new Student("DeBanque, Robin", 8812);
```

Given that person[] is **declared** to be of type **Person,** you would expect, for example, in the third line where person[0] is initialized to a new Undergraduate object,to only gain the instance variable from Person and Persons Methods since doesn't the assignment to a new Undergraduate to it's ancestor denote the Undergraduate object to access Person - it's Ancestors, methods and isntance variables...

Thus ...with the following code I would expect

```
  person[0].writeOutput();  // calls Undergraduate::writeOutput()
  person[1].writeOutput();  // calls Student::writeOutput()
```

person[0] to not have Undergraduate's writeOutput() overidden method, nor have person[1] to have Student's overidden method - writeOutput().

If I had

```
Person mikeJones = new Student("Who?,MikeJones",44,4);
mikeJones.writeOutput();
```

The Person::writeOutput() method would be called.

Why is this not so? Does it have to do with something I don't understand about relating to arrays? Does the declaration Person[] people = new Person[2] not bind the method like the previous code would?

Comment: See http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/java-questions/dynamic-binding/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing to do with arrays, it is the effect of the "late binding". The Java compiler only checks that Person has the `writeOutput` method, but does not bind the call to that class method. The binding is performed at runtime, where the JVM finds that Person[0] is an `UnderGraduate` and calls the method definition from `UnderGraduate`, and not the one from `Person`.

I understand that C++ works the other way unless you specify `virtual`, but it is better this way (if you think that a class encapsulates data and methods, you ensure that the methods used are the ones which really matter to the encapsulated data).

Comment: It's worth noting that C++ requires you to explicitly declare virtual because of performance and template implications. Not because it's better for OOP that way. It's just impossible the other

Comment: Wouldn't this code call Person::writeOutput()?

     'Person mikeJones = new Student("Who?,MikeJones",44,4);
     mikeJones.writeOutput();'

Comment: Again, no. Late binding means that the binding is to the object's actual class and its methods.

Comment: @SJuan76 Oh I thought my textbook said otherwise. Hmmmm. Thanks though.